# How to navigate back through one navigationController and another navigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Here I have:

```
SplitViewController >> 1. NavigationController >> MainViewController >> NavigationController>> DetailViewControllerA
```

another link from SplitViewController above

```
NavigationController >> mainDetailViewController >> NavigationController >> DetailViewControllerA
```

I'd like to create a back button manually on `DetailViewControllerA` when navigating from `mainDetailViewController`.
But how to go back from `DetailViewControllerA` to `mainDetailViewController`?

When I used

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

It's only `nil`

Thanks.

Comment: `NavigationController >> MainViewController >> NavigationController>> DetailViewControllerA` why are you assigning `DetailViewControllerA` a new `NavigationController` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
NavigationController >> MainViewController >> NavigationController>> DetailViewControllerA
```

There is no need of assigning `DetailViewControllerA` a new `NavigationController`

This is how it should be:

```
NavigationController >> MainViewController >> DetailViewControllerA
```

When you want to push to `DetailViewControllerA` screen, you just need to push your `DetailViewControllerA` like this.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewControllerA") as! DetailViewControllerA
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Then in `DetailViewControllerA`, you can easily call `popViewController` on back button press(if using manual button, otherwise back button will show by default with pop functionality)